# What is the difference between a kernel and a function?

Tags: functions, definition

I have been looking around for this question, but all results I found only describe the definition and not the answer I seek.

Is "kernel" basically a synonym of "function"? When should be the time we should use the word "kernel" instead of "function"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Kernel" is an old-fashioned term for the function you use to define certain [integral operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform). (I assume this is the sense you mean, not the more common modern sense, which is [completely different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)).) Like many other words in mathematics (although people generally never tell you this), it has less to do with denotation than connotation: when you use the word "kernel" you are thinking of your function in terms of integral operators.

Comment: Is it old-fashioned? What would you name the Fejér kernel then in modern language? It looks to me like it is still in use in harmonic analysis.

Comment: @Jonas: "old-fashioned" doesn't mean "out of use." Perhaps that was bad choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't synonymous. A kernel is a property of a function. Most generically, if you have a function $f: X \to Y$, it is defined as the equivalence relation on X which identifies $x_1$ and $x_2$ if and only if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

There are specialisations of this depending on the category $f$ lives in: for example, if $f$ is a group homomorphism, the homogeneity of the group structure means that we can represent this equivalence relation as the normal subgroup $\{ x \in X : f(x) = e \}$. Similarly for $f$ a linear map of vector spaces, or modules, or rings.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you said...

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP means.

Answer (score 1):

A kernel is not a synonym for a function. As Zhen Lin said, it is a property of of a function.

I will try to explain the kernel of a map in linear algebra. Suppose we have a linear map $L:V\rightarrow W$. Then the kernel of $L$ consists of all vectors in $V$ which are mapped to zero. $0$ is always mapped to zero, thus the kernel is never empty. It is easy to prove that the kernel of $L$ is always a linear subspace of $V$. If $v,w\in V$ are vectors in the kernel of $L$, that is $Lv=Lw=0$, then $L(\lambda v+\mu w)=\lambda Lv+\mu L w=\lambda 0+\mu 0=0$. Thus any linear combination of vectors in the kernel is an element of the kernel. Hence it is a linear subspace of $V$.

This idea generalizes to a lot of other mathematical constructions (e.g. groups), this was what Zhen Lin was talking about.

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same. A kernel is a set of elements in the domain whereas a function is a mapping from the domain to the codomain.

Compare [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28mathematics%29) and [function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)