# Conceptual Understanding of Kernels

Tags: mathematical-physics

In the previous thread ([Difference between kernel and function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22133/difference-between-kernel-and-function)) the question of the difference between a kernel and a function came to, in my mind, an unclear conclusion.

Am I right in thinking that a kernel is the property of certain functions to map from one space to another?  Or am I grossly missing the point? My current professors tend to throw the term around, but I've never clearly understood their meaning.

If someone has an explanation to help my understanding I would greatly appreciate the help.

-Drew

Comment: If you are interested in kernels used in optimization theory (e.g., Machine Learning, Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces), then I tried to give a brief answer.

Comment: @simonrose, you are correct, I am concerned with the integral transform sense.  While I understand what Qiaochu Yuan wrote, I thought there was something else being described other than a statement that the function should be thought of in terms of integral operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics the word *kernel* is used for two completely different purposes:

In algebra: Given a homomorphism $f:\>G\to H$ between groups the *kernel* of $f$ is the set of all $x\in G$ which map to the unit element $e\in H$. In particular, if $f:\> V\to W$ is a linear map between vector spaces, the *kernel* of $f$ is the subspace $K\subset V$ consisting of the vectors $x\in V$ which are mapped to $0\in W$.

In analysis or mathematical physics we often deal with situations of the following kind: Given is a function $$k:\quad \>A\times B\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (x,y)\mapsto k(x,y)\ ,$$
defined on some cartesian product space $A\times B$. One uses integration over $A$ to obtain for any function $$f:\quad A\to{\mathbb R},\qquad x\mapsto f(x)$$ a new function $f^T$ defined on $B$ in the following way:
$$f^T(y):=\int_A k(x,y) f(x)\ dx\qquad(y\in B)\ .\tag{1}$$
When the function $k$ is used in this way it is called the *kernel* for this transformation. Examples are the kernel $k(t,s):=e^{-st}$ used in the Laplace transform or kernels of the form $k(x,y):={1\over|x-y|^\alpha}$ occurring in differential geometry or potential theory. A last example: When the first factor $g$ in a convolution $g*f$ is fixed once and for all and only the second factor $f$ is considered "variable" then the function $k(t,x):=g(x-t)$ can be considered as a "kernel" in the above sense.

The function $k(\cdot,\cdot)$ in these examples works like  a "continuous version" of a matrix: Given an $m\times n$-matrix $[t_{ik}]$ we obtain for any input vector $x=(x_1,\ldots x_n)$ (which can be thought of as a function on $[n]$) an output vector $x^T=(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ (a function on $[m]$) by means of the following formula, which is completely analogous to $(1)$:
$$y_i=\sum_{k=1}^n t_{ik}\>x_k\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)\ .$$

Comment: does this then mean that convolutions are making use of a kernel? Or am I now confusing two ideas?

Comment: @DrewW: See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another field where the kernels are used is in optimization theory (or in machine learning). There, kernels are functions defined on some $D\times D$ set, where typically $D$ is required to be merely a non-empty set. Kernels are usually used as dissimilarity measures. We use them when mapping from some vector space (say $n$-dimensional) into another, often richer $d$-dimensional space, is needed. $d$ is mostly greater than $n$, typically $d\gg n$, but it could also be infinite-dimensional. Kernels need to be positive-definite, and this way they reproduce some Hilbert Space uniquely. For instance, if $D=\Bbb{R}^n$, then we can define the Radial Basis Function (RBF) as $k\colon\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, with 
$$
k(x,x')=\exp(-\gamma\|x-x'\|^2),
$$
where $\gamma$ is some positive parameter. This function measures the similarity of $x,x'$, but essentially represents the inner product $<\phi(x),\phi(x')>$, where $\phi$ mapps $\Bbb{R}^n$ to an infinite-dimensional space. The trick is that, whenever a dot product appears (i.e., $x\cdot x'$) we can replace it by $<\phi(x),\phi(x')>$, and thus by $k(x,x')$ without even knowing explicitely the mapping $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

The word *kernel* has several meanings in mathematics. This was already remarked in the different answers to the question [Difference between kernel and function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22133/difference-between-kernel-and-function). If you say the conclusion was unclear, you should clarify which kernel you mean. 
For me, a conceptual understanding of the kernel is the categorial kernel:
The *kernel* of a morphism $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is indeed a morphism, namely the "most general" morphism $k\colon K\rightarrow X$ that yields zero when composed with $f$ (i.e., with $f\circ k=0$).

Comment: It's worth noting that given the question, the asker is most likely not asking about the kernel in the algebraic sense, but more likely in the integral transform sense.

Comment: Or maybe he is interested in the way they are used under the machine learning (or just optimization) area... I'm not sure but I guess so, because he wrote about mappings from one space to another.

Comment: @SimonRose But for that case there was already a good answer given by Qiaochu Yuan (see the above link). Since the OP says that there was an "unclear conclusion", he must mean something else.